# Слетают выбранные чекбоксы и инпуты при перерисовке компонента

Tags: reactjs, render

У меня есть состояние questions, массив, что я получаю от сервера, при первом подключении, устанавливаю состояние setQuestions равное вопросам (билетам) от сервера. Затем я отображаю их с помощью questions.map. У меня используются UI компоненты в этих билетах  что рендерю, и при получении новых билетов, те, что чекнул пользователь (radio/input/checkbox) слетают. Решил использовать React.memo, чтобы отображать те билеты, которых нет в quesitons, помогло, при получении новых билетов действия перестали слетать, однако теперь не знаю, как вызвать перерисовку теперь тех билетов, у которых изменилось свойство checked на true. Т.е какой-то пользователь проголосовал в билете, билет попал на сервер, и разослал всем клиентам, что данный вопрос уже решен. Но как вызвать перерисовку этого билета ?

Теперь говоря проще, мне нужно обновлять билеты, но так, чтобы значения выбранных пользователем чекбоксов и инпутов при перерисовки билетов не слетало. В идеале конечно чтобы перерисовывались только те билеты, что новые и у которых checked = true. Но буду благодарен, если покажите даже простое решение с перерисовкой всех билетов, и сохранением выбранного пользователем действия. Я больше по нативному JS, потому в React не такой подкованный.

```
//предотвращение перерисовки всех компонентов
const QuestionItem = React.memo(({ question }) => {

    return (
        <Question
            type={question.type}
            questionId={question.id}
            images={question.images}
            qNum={question.number}
            vNum={0}
            title={question.title}
            selects={question.selects}
        />
    );
});
... код

//комната
const Room = () => {

    //вопросы (билеты)
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    ... код
    
    //обработчик новых вопросов
    const incQuestionHandler = (request) => {
        setQuestions((prevItems) => [...prevItems, request.data]);
    }

    //первичная загрузка билетов
    useEffect(() => {
        //получение билетов
        emitGetQuest(getRoomQuests);

        //прослушивание билетов
        socket.on('update-question-data', incQuestionHandler);

        //убрать прослушку
        return () => {
            socket.off('update-question-data', incQuestionHandler);
        }
    }, [])
    
return (... код
<div className='center-content'>
    <VoteInfo/>
    {questions.map((question, n) => ( <--------- отрисовка билетов
        <QuestionItem key={question.id} question={question}/>
    ))}
</div>
)
```

Я также пробовал просто перерисовывать все билеты, не прибегая к React.memo, тестировал на небольшим компоненте, где все работало, и чекбоксы и инпуты не слетали, однако это не работает для компонента Questions, в нем в свою очередь также идет отрисовка вариантов ответов с помощью map, вот код:

```
//билеты
const Question = (props) => {

    //установить варианты ответов для вопроса
    const QuestionSelection = (props) => {
        const {parentProps} = props;

        //билет
        let element;

        //проверка на тип билета
        switch(parentProps.type){
            case 'radio':
                element = <Radio selects={parentProps.selects} questionId={parentProps.questionId}/>
                break
            case 'checkbox':
                element = <Check selects={parentProps.selects} questionId={parentProps.questionId}/>
                break
            case 'dropout':
                element = <Dropout selects={parentProps.selects} questionId={parentProps.questionId}/>
                break
            case 'input':
                element = <TextInput maxLength='250' questionId={parentProps.questionId}/>
                break
            default:
                element = null
                break
        }

        return element;
    }

...код

    return (
...код
//ТУТ ОТРИСОВЫВАЕТСЯ ТИП БИЛЕТА В QuestionSelection
                <div className='middle-quest-content'>
                    <div className='quest-title-content'>
                        <img className='test-info-icon' src={questIcon}></img>
                        <span className='simple-span test-info-text'><ParseTextAndInsertImages images={props.images} title={props.title}/></span>
                    </div>
                    <QuestionSelection parentProps={props}/>
                </div>
...код
    )
}

export default Question;
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, я немного не вник, и мне следовало передавать checked в пропс мемонизированного компонента, чтобы вызвать его перерисовку.

```
return (... код
<div className='center-content'>
    <VoteInfo/>
    {questions.map((question, n) => ( <--------- отрисовка билетов
        <QuestionItem checked={question.checked} key={question.id} question={question}/>
    ))}
</div>
```